# How do I relate PBI on ADO board to the corresponding Deployment and Development

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When I go to a PBI on my ADO board. I can see all this metadata like title, work item ID, description, pbi type, priority, state, area, iteration. These are few but I can see lots of useful information about the PBI.

I can also access lots of this information via ADP API calls.

Is there a query or API call I can use to find out the deployment and development that is related to work items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a query or API call I can use to find out the deployment and development that is related to work items?

Yes. To meet your requirement, you can use the Rest API: [Work Items - Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP) and add the **$expand** parameter in the URL.

Rest API: Set **$expand=all** or **$expand=relations**

```
   GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?$expand=all&api-version=7.1-preview.3
```

Then you can check the **relations value** in the response. It will contains all information in Development and Deployment tab.

For example:

[image]

API Response:

[image]